# nunique excluding some values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am calculating unique values, per row. However I want to exclude the value 0 and then calculate uniques

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 0], 'col3': [0, 4, 0],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1    col2    col3
0   1       3       0
1   2       4       4
2   3       0       0
```

Expected output

```
    col1    col2    col3    uniques
0   1       3       0       2
1   2       4       4       2
2   3       0       0       1
```

`df.nunique(axis = 1)`, this includes all values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you can simply replace zeroes with Nan values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [3, 4, 0], 'col3': [0, 4, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['uniques'] =  df.replace(0, np.NaN).nunique(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def func(x):
    s = set(x)
    s.discard(0)
    return len(s)

df['uniq'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more concise version without using `replace`:

```
df['unique'] = df[df!=0].nunique(axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  unique
0     1     3     0       2
1     2     4     4       2
2     3     0     0       1
```