# pandas unique values with condition

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, unique

I am working with a pandas DataFrame and I need to loop trough the unique values of a column. 
Such columns might contain values that i dont want to loop through, for instance ''

normally I do:

```
edges = [edge for edge in estados['EDGE'].unique() if edge != '']
for edge in edges:
    pass
```

my question is if there is a more pandonic way to build up the list different than the conprehension list.

like:

```
estados['EDGE'].unique().exclude('')
```

THANKS

Note:
I looked for solutions like in:
[nunique excluding some values in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074857/nunique-excluding-some-values-in-pandas)
[Python pandas unique value ignoring NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218652/python-pandas-unique-value-ignoring-nan/46218844)
but these solutions are even less concise as mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`pd.Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and [`pd.Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)

```
m = estados['EDGE']==''
estados['EDGE'].mask(m).dropna().unique()
```

Or with [`pd.Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html)

```
m = (estados['EDGE']!='') & (estados['EDGE'].notna())

estados['EDGE'][m]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT operator `~`:

```
estados[~estados['EDGE'] == '']['EDGE'].dropna().unique()
```

**OR** Use [`.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
estados[estados['EDGE'].ne('')]['EDGE'].dropna().unique()
```